# Icons for drawing architecture diagrams

Tags: icons, diagrams

Do you know any repository of icons for drawing system architecture diagram? Something with nice and tidy server, database, client icons, etc.

Comment: I know programs that have that, but a repository? Nope.

Comment: Is it something other than MS Visio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find [IconFinder](http://www.iconfinder.com/) to be pretty handy for finding icons (imagine that!). Lots of different styles and sizes available for the ones I checked (database, server).

You can tune your search based on the size you want and whether the icons are freely usable or not (they have both kinds).

Answer (score 1):

See database icons at:

http://www.perfect-icons.com/stock-icons/perfect-database-icons.htm

Answer (score 1):

I found free [OSA Icon Library](http://www.opensecurityarchitecture.org/cms/library/icon-library) very useful:

[SVG Icon Download](http://www.opensecurityarchitecture.org/downloads/13_05_osa_icons_svg.zip), 
[PNG Icon Download](http://www.opensecurityarchitecture.org/downloads/13_05_osa_icons_png.zip)

Preview of library:

[image: Small scale library overview]

Answer (score 0):

[Flaticon](http://www.flaticon.com) should be mentioned as most icons are released under CC BY 3.0. They provide a considerable amount of flat icons for servers and other IT hardware / services that easily fit in a diagram.